# Break RSA knowing N, e, dp+dq

Tags: rsa

In a cryptography exercise, I have to factor $N$ only knowing $e$ and $d_p+d_q$ (not $d_p$ and $d_q$ separately).

I came up with the following equations:
$$e*(d_p+d_q) = 2+K_p(p-1)+K_q(q-1)$$
$$e*d_p \equiv 1 \pmod{p-1} \implies 1 +K_p(p-1)\bmod e = 0 $$
$$e*d_q \equiv 1 \pmod{q-1} \implies 1 +K_q(q-1)\bmod e = 0 $$

Probably have to bruteforce Kp and Kq, but am not sure on how to proceed.

Comment: On second thought, the idea of brute-forcing the possible values of $(K_p,K_q)$ seems good. For each, the first equation gives a relation between $p$ and $q$, which on top of $N=pq$ leads to (at most) two solutions in reals that we could find. We are looking for one that is in integers.